# Finding limit of this tricky expression

Tags: calculus, limits

What is the limit of $\dfrac{1}{t\sqrt{1+t}} - \dfrac{1}{t}$ as $t$ approaches zero?  I asked the teacher and he couldn't solve it, so I'm asking you.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Edit:  I'm very sorry people.  I typed the problem incorrectly at first.

Comment: Your teacher's got a problem.

Comment: Haha, that's no joke.  Can you solve it?

Comment: Yes, if $t$ is close to $0$ but positive, our function is big positive.  If negative, our function is big negative. Limit does not exist.

Comment: But if you want to change the problem, then the answer might change.

Comment: I just edited your question using $\LaTeX$ to make it easier to read. Please check to make sure the expression I wrote is correct.

Comment: How many times do you want to change the question?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Perform a bit of algebraic manipulation as follows:

$\dfrac{1}{t\sqrt{1+t}}-\dfrac{1}{t} = \dfrac{1-\sqrt{1+t}}{t\sqrt{1+t}} = \dfrac{1-\sqrt{1+t}}{t\sqrt{1+t}} \cdot \dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+t}}{1+\sqrt{1+t}}$

$= \dfrac{1-(1-t)}{t\sqrt{1+t}(1+\sqrt{1+t})} = \dfrac{-t}{t\sqrt{1+t}(1+\sqrt{1+t})} = \dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{1+t}(1+\sqrt{1+t})}$.

Now, let $t \to 0$ and see what you get.

Comment: I'm a fool.  Thank you JimmyK4542.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with Taylor expansion, you can solve it without many algebraic manipulations.

First observe that $\sqrt{1+t} = 1 + t/2 + o(t)$.
Now:
$$\lim_{t \to 0} \left ( \frac 1 {t\sqrt{1+t}} - \frac 1 {t} \right ) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 + t}}{t\sqrt{1+t}} \sim \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1 - (1 + t/2)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} -\frac t {2t} = -\frac 12$$.